# How can I set the peak voltage in an AC waveform?

Tags: ac, generator, electromagnetic

I am trying to make a small generator, nothing fancy just a coil of wire, and I was curious as to how the peak voltage of the waveform could be changed. Is the only way to increase this voltage with a transformer, or can I set it based off of RPMs?

Comment: The voltage is directly proportional to the rpm.

Comment: More turns! same way a transformer has more turns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EMF (voltage) of a coil in a generator [is the negative of the rate of change of magnetic flux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction#Mathematical_statement) that passes through the coil. You have a few ways to increase this:

1. Use a stronger magnetic field (i.e. more flux)
2. Use more turns of wire, allowing the same field to "count" multiple times
3. Use more coils (same as one coil with more turns, really)
4. Change the magnetic flux faster (i.e. higher RPMs)

You will probably find it more convenient to adjust the generator design, than to add more parts and make a more complicated circuit.